# QGIS low CPU usage why?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, rendering, speed

I work with the latest QGIS program on bike trail maps. I monitor my CPU and memory usage and for years the CPU usage hovers around 20%, never to peak or even hit 50%.

This just seems odd that I have to wait for tasks to get done when there is still so much headroom to get it done faster. Is this normal?

I work on a Win 10 computer with an i7, 16MB Ram, new video card etc. it flies.

And yes I have set it to use all cores, work with Geopackage files, clip my maps smaller...

Would setting up a DB with QGIS tap into more power?

The time lost in slow processing and rendering doing 66 maps is a real problem.

Comment: Settings -> Options -> Rendering and activate Render layers in parallel using many CPU cores (you can set the number)

Comment: Thanks, I know about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A 100% usage display would imply that *all* CPU cores were being simultaneously fully utilized, no matter how many physical cores the CPU contained (2, 4, 8...).  But many software applications are only capable of accessing one core at a time; with the other cores idling.  Utilizing such "single-threaded" software on a multi-core machine will never reach a 100% reading.  For example, the maximum CPU reading possible while running single-threaded software on a 4-core CPU is 25%: one core fully utilized, three idling.  On a 2-core machine, the same software would register a 50% maximum reading.

QGIS is a bit of a hybrid; some functions are single-threaded while others (i.e. rendering) are multi-threaded.

Comment: Hmm good to know that this is all QGIS can work with and that I have not missed some settings that could boost it. It's a shame that there is such a low CPU limit of one core most of the time.